# How to control Multiple Address Checkout on Magento admin settings?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping-address

How to disable the 'Ship to Multiple Address' option from cart page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable the "Checkout with Multiple Addresses" option on your Magento website. Here's how:

```
1. Login to your Magento site's Admin Panel
2. Go to System and select Configuration
3. Go to Shipping Settings on the left menu under Sales section
4. Set "Allow Shipping to multiple addresses" to "No"
5. Save Config
```

If you do not see any changes make sure the Magento Cache is cleared

```
1. Go to System and select Cache Management
2. Refresh the cache and check your site again.
```

Reference: http://ode2code.blogspot.ae/2010/06/disabling-multiple-address-checkout-on.html